# Combining items from list using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join

I have used regular expressions to parse a file and locate the name and price of the following currencies. Note that both of these items (x=name/y=price) inserted into lists. I have used a join statement on top of this:

```
print("\n".join(x + (y)))
```

```
"name":"Bitcoin"

"name":"Ethereum"

"name":"Tether"

"price":21335.75253

"price":1592.06118

"price":1.00015`
```

From here, I am *trying* to get the following display:

```
"name":"Bitcoin" - "price":21335.75253

"name":"Ethereum" - "price":1592.06118

"name":"Tether" - "price":1.00015`
```

The only way I can get the intended display, is by using the following:

```
print(x[0],y[0])
```

`"name":"Bitcoin" "price":21335.75253`

Ideally I can use a for loop inside both slices, but I'm not sure thats possible.

Answer (score 1):

"zip" should do the trick.

```
for name, price in zip(x, y):
    print('"name":"{}" - "price":{}'.format(name, price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function that combines any number of lists together. It's important that the longest list is the first argument in the function call so you can combine it like `print("\n".join(list(zip(x, y))))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x = ['"name":"Bitcoin"', '"name":"Ethereum"', '"name":"Tether"']
y = ['"price":21335.75253', '"price":1592.06118', '"price":1.00015']
print('\n'.join([f'{name} - {price}' for name, price in zip(x,y)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
print('\n'.join(f'{i[0]} - {i[1]}' for i in zip(x, y)))
```